# How to use jquery-scrollTo for many div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i use  jquery-scrollTo on many divs. Let's say I have the following div

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#grid" class="scrollto">Grid System</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tooltips" class="scrollto">Tooltips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tables" class="scrollto">Tables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#carousel" class="scrollto">Carousel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#thumbnails" class="scrollto">Thumbnails</a></li>
    <li><a href="#forms" class="scrollto">Forms</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then on my divs I have:

```
<section class="intro-features" id="grid">
</section>
<section class="intro-features" id="tooltips">
</section>
<section class="intro-features" id="tables">
</section>
<section class="intro-features" id="carousel">
</section>
```

So basically, you will call it the jQuery scrool To using this:

```
<script>
    $("div#div1").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("div#myDiv").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Is there any idea? https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Comment: Use same class on all `div`s and use it to bind click event, and `this` inside the handler to get offset.

Comment: show me the solution specifically

Comment: **HTML:** `<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>`. **JS:** `$(".div").click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});`

Comment: It doesn't work. Can you show the solution on JSFIDDLE? I updated my codes above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

No plugins needed, just jQuery:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.getAttribute("href")).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
section {
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#grid" class="scrollto">Grid System</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tooltips" class="scrollto">Tooltips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tables" class="scrollto">Tables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#carousel" class="scrollto">Carousel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#thumbnails" class="scrollto">Thumbnails</a></li>
    <li><a href="#forms" class="scrollto">Forms</a></li>
</ul>

<section class="intro-features" id="grid">
</section>
<section class="intro-features" id="tooltips">
</section>
<section class="intro-features" id="tables">
</section>
<section class="intro-features" id="carousel">
</section>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8weqhsr/)